# Where is DoCmd.OpenQuery Located

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to using VBA scripts in Access db.

I have a grandfathered db which has the following snippet

```
Dim My_Selected_Pool() As String
Dim My_Selected_Scenario() As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Dist_Cons1", , acReadOnly
```

I have looked around everywhere but I am unable to locate `Dist_Cons1`. This query creates tables and populates it after processing some other existing tables in the database. When I use debug option it doesn't step into the query either.

Comment: This is a query named `Dist_Cons1`, so it should be under queries on the navigation pane on the left (in Access, not the VBA editor).

Comment: What tab is that ?

Comment: Queries? Right below Tables.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-navigation-pane-274dfc5a-281b-472b-94e2-ef931c5cc590 -- One query can create/populate one table only, not multiple.

Comment: Is this a split db? Is the backend an Access file or SQLServer? Query cannot be 'step debugged'.